# Which one is better to inspect elements in html? firebug in firefox or IE developer tool?

Tags: firebug

I think firebug is the better one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without any hesitation [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) is the best tool for web developers.

Answer (score 2):

A vote for Firebug here.  IE's developer tool, like the rest of IE, is clunky and badly done.

Answer (score 1):

Firebug wins, hands down. Since Firefox is getting lots of flak for being slow these days (we should wait for FF 4), a lot of people say that Firebug is Firefox's saving grace. The only thing that's close is Chrome's developer tools.

Comment: agreed.  I generally use Chrome for 90% of what I do, and switch to FF for javascript issues and debugging.  But I don't use FF for regular day-to-day development/browsing.  I'm one of those keeping it around to check for compatibility and use Firebug.

Comment: Chrome's dev tools is better IMO. In chrome you can see all the event listeners that are attached to the element, I'm almost certain you can't do that in FF:FB

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe [LIVEditor](http://liveditor.com)'s built-in html inspector is not the best, but at least **you don't need to manually** copy your tweaked `html/css` code back to your text/code editor :)

PS, I'm the developer of LIVEditor :)

Answer (score 0):

Firebug is better not only for inspecting html but to see headers, responses, etc too, handy for javascript developer.

Thing that bugs me is that everytime I use Aurora's firebug my laptop will turn bluescreen in 20-30 minutes (error is something like IRQL_DRIVER_LESS_THAN_EQUAL in Event Viewer, sorry if this is getting off topic)